# NEAT algorithm, Function definition missing from provided libraries

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

Ive been trying to implement the NeuroEvolution of Augmenting Topologies( NEAT) algorithm for a flappy bird clone, referring a tutorial on youtube.

Following the tutorial Ive run into the following problem:
When executing `index.html` I receive the following error.

```
TypeError: func is not a function matrix.js:104:27
```

This is confusing as `matrix.js` and `nn.js`are both library functions provided to me by the person conducting the tutorial.

Looking at the code of matrix.js I found that the line throwing the error was

```
this.data[i][j] = func(val,i,j);
```

but I could not find a function definition for the function `func()` anywhere in either `matrix.js` or `nn.js`.

But in the code of `nn.js` I found that `func` was being referred to as a variable and not a function.

```
class ActivationFunction {
  constructor(func, dfunc) {
    this.func = func;
    this.dfunc = dfunc;
  }
}

let sigmoid = new ActivationFunction(
  x => 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x)),
  y => y * (1 - y)
);

let tanh = new ActivationFunction(
  x => Math.tanh(x),
  y => 1 - (y * y)
);
```

and

```
setActivationFunction(func = sigmoid) {
    this.activation_function = func;
  }
```

So I assumed that func was meant to provide the sigmoid value of `val` to  `this.data[I][j]` so I wrote my own sigmoid function which fed the activation function values to `this.data[I][j]`. which upon execution threw the error 
`ReferenceError: NeuralNetwork is not defined[Learn More] bird.js:25:7`

Therefore I decided to abandon trying to write a function and I decided to copy the value of the sigmoid activation function directly into the variable `this.data[I][j]` as follows:

```
this.data[i][j] = 1/(1+Math.pow(Math.E, -val));
```

This method did not throw any errors but did present me with a new problem.
Earlier each member of the population of each generation would be acting independently producing an output like this:
[image: Correct Output]

But now what im getting is 
[image: Incorrect Output]

Its not that only one player object is being generated in the second image all 250 objects are being generated but they're all on top of one another making it seem like theres only one player object. This is due to

```
1/(1+Math.pow(Math.E, -val));
```

sending the exact same value to `this.data[I][j]`, I've observed that when different values are passed to `this.data[I][j]` each player object acts independently. 
Does anyone have any idea as to why func is. variable in one file and func is a function in another file?

I apologise for my lack of clarity as this is an error in the library files, I am not an expert on matrix operations and I have tried to convey the problem I'm facing to the best of my ability. No one I know so far has been facing these issues.

All the required files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X0C3I0fk0DNFWduEqyz3JVGNEf-haGJS)

Comment: `this.data[i][j] = this.func`?

Comment: @Adelin Didnt work :/

Comment: do you get the point? the point is you declare func as part of the constructor using `this` keyord, but later, all over the place, you use it as an unbound variable. Use `this.func` wherever want to call the `func` initially declared as `this.func`

Comment: @Adelin I see what you mean, I tried using the this.func and I still have the same issue